# Access Dictionary Items within Method Override

Tags: c#, task, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have the below class in a webapi which adds to the dictionary however everytime the checkstatus method is triggered (using Task.Delay) it says the dictionary is empty. Is this because its running on a different thread? Should I be using a concurrentdictionary instead?

```
internal class Sms : smsBase
{
    private const int CheckFrequencyMilliseconds = 1000;
    private Dictionary<CustomerDetails, decimal> _registeredCustomers;

    public Sms(ILogger<Sms> logger)
        : base(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(CheckFrequencyMilliseconds), logger)
    {
        _registeredCustomers = new Dictionary<CustomerDetails, decimal>();
    }

    protected override Task CheckStatus()
    {

        foreach (var rc in _registeredCustomers)
        {
         //do something
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task RegisterCustomer(CustomerDetails customer)
    {
        _registeredCustomers.Add(customer, 1);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Base class code below.

```
public abstract class smsBase : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _tickFrequency;
    private readonly ILogger<smsBase> _logger;

/// <inheritdoc />
/// <param name="tickFrequency">Frequency that the service will execute the CheckStatus method.</param>
protected smsBase (TimeSpan tickFrequency,ILogger<smsBase> logger)
{
  this._tickFrequency = tickFrequency;
  this._logger = logger;
}

/// <inheritdoc />
protected override sealed async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  this._logger.LogInformation("Service is starting.");
  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    ConfiguredTaskAwaitable configuredTaskAwaitable;
    try
    {
      configuredTaskAwaitable = this.CheckStatus().ConfigureAwait(false);
      await configuredTaskAwaitable;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      this._logger.LogError(ex, "An exception was thrown whilst checking registered strategies.");
      throw;
    }
    configuredTaskAwaitable = Task.Delay(this._tickFrequency, stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await configuredTaskAwaitable;
  }
  this._logger.LogInformation("Service is stopping.");

protected abstract Task CheckStatus();
}
```

And below is the startup cs

```
    public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddSwaggerGen(options => {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info() { Title = "Customers.WebApi", Version = "v1" });
            })
            .AddMvc(options => {
                options.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
                options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });

        services.AddHostedService<Sms>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISms, Sms>();
    }
```

Comment: Are you running `CheckStatus` on the same instance that you run `RegisterCustomer` on?  We really need to see how you're using this class to determine the problem.

Comment: FYI, IIS will occasionally restart your web app (see "app recycling") - so unless the data you're working with is persisted somewhere, you may be loosing it that way.

Comment: @juharr I believe on the same instance. I've added more code to help.

Comment: Web applications are _stateless_. Unless you have added something like Hangfire or Quartz.NET to your project, then the concept of a long-running or repeated / scheduled task is nonsensical. Each HTTP request is processed in isolation. the .NET code basically runs once per request, and stops at the end of the request. Each time it acts as if the code has never been run before. Variable values are not persisted between requests unless you specifically write code to save (and then retrieve) data.

Comment: @ADyson I think you're missing that this is a [hosted service](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/13/hosted-services-in-asp-net-core/), not an http request.

Comment: @Jamiec that's a new one on me, thanks. Haven't done anything with this kind of stuff yet (although I probably should!). OP could perhaps have mentioned this in the question, though... they described it as Web API, hence my comment.

Comment: First, there is too much code here. Second, I don’t see where your “Add” method is ever called.

Comment: where is the code that calls RegisterCustomer (which adds items to the dictionary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many points missing from your question, but I believe I can derive the problem from just these 2 lines

```
services.AddHostedService<Sms>();
services.AddSingleton<ISms, Sms>();
```

The `AddSingleton` line will create a single instance of `Sms` for your application, and I suspect you're injecting `ISms` into a controller somewhere and calling `RegisterCustomer`.

The `AddHostedService` line will create a *second* instance of Sms, and use it as the hosted service.

The solution is to split these 2 things apart, and have something like `ICustomerRepository` which is shared by both the hosted service and the controllers.

---

Note that if I'm well off the mark here, it would help to edit your question with the details of `ISms`, including how it is used, and where you call `RegisterCustomer`.

Comment: you are correct, I have a controller that ISms is being injected into however I think I may have solved this by declaring my dictionary as static. I'll test it out further otherwise will do as you say and create an ICustomerRepository.

Comment: @Elias yep, a static dictionary will be shared by the 2 instances. Not the most elegant solution, but will probably work in most cases.

Comment: the shared IRepository could that be a simple class that instantiates,adds and removes from a dictionary?

Comment: @Elias yep, register it singleton, and inject *that* into your Hosted Service and Controller. Remove your registration of ISms/Sms and separate those concerns.